# Allow only Admin Key-User to delete the form

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I want to allow only the user that have Admin Key-User as role to delete the form , now also the Admin Key-User can't delete if the conditions in trigger are corrects .

=>this is my trigger

```
trigger FormBeforeDelete on CORE_Form__c (before delete) {
    
    Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    
    //Profile profileName = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=' Admin Key-Use']; 
    
    //if (profileName !='Total Retail France Admin Key-User ' ){
     
     for (CORE_Form__c form : trigger.old )
        
    {
        system.debug('teste');
         // if(Trigger.isBefore){}

        if(form.CreatedById != currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'Validated')
        {
            form.addError('Cannot delete form - you are not the owner & the status is Validated');
        } 
        
        if(form.CreatedById == currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'Validated')
        {
            form.addError('Cannot delete form -  the status is Validated');
        } 
        
        
         if(form.CreatedById != currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'Finished')
        {
            form.addError('Cannot delete form - you are not the owner');
        } 
        
         if(form.CreatedById != currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'In Progress')
        {
            form.addError('Cannot delete form - you are not the owner');
        } 
    }

    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

If you are saying that the trigger did not work to allow that role to delete *before the two lines were commented out* and that is what you need help with, then you need to consider your `SELECT` statement.  In it you look for the Profile having the `Name`:

```
'Total Retail France Admin Key-Use'
```

Then in your `if` statement you reference the the Profile name as:

```
'Total Retail France Admin Key-User '
```

Those are not the same.

However, even after correcting that issue your trigger would not work in the way you intend, because you never compare that Profile with the current user's Profile.

There are other items of concern with this trigger including logic that can be cleaned up and the consideration of putting your "working" code in a trigger helper class.  But to concentrate on the immediate issue: If you wish to allow deletion by that Profile every time with no other conditions, you could do something like:

```
trigger FormBeforeDelete on CORE_Form__c (before delete) {
    Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    Id currentUserProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
    String profileName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :currentUserProfileId].Name;
        
    if (profileName !='Total Retail France Admin Key-User'){
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Hello , your solution is correct , thank you